# Raven_visualization package

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some urdf files of surgical robot Raven. When I open it in RViz I get the error :

> 

[rospack] Error: stack/package raven_visualization not found

> [librospack]: error while executing command
> [ERROR] [1383833639.703512879]: Could not load resource [package://raven_visualization/Raven_files/left_arm/wrist.dae]: Unable to open file "package://raven_visualization/Raven_files/left_arm/wrist.dae".
> [ERROR] [1383833639.703785780]: Could not load model 'package://raven_visualization/Raven_files/left_arm/wrist.dae' for link 'wrist_L': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://raven_visualization/Raven_files/left_arm/wrist.dae in resource group >Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
> [ERROR] [1383833639.703993963]: Could not load model 'package://raven_visualization/Raven_files/left_arm/wrist.dae' for link 'wrist_L': OGRE >EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://raven_visualization/Raven_files/left_arm/wrist.dae in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)

Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98721/raven_visualization-package/) by [Akshay_Bhardwaj_nsit](https://answers.ros.org/users/8321/akshay_bhardwaj_nsit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem!

---

source devel/setup.bash

---

by this command I solved my problem!

---

Originally posted by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) with karma: 206 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0